# Managed Extensibility Framework, Interception and Dynamic Proxy

Tags: c#, mef, castle-dynamicproxy

easy task, but couldn't find any direction.

i want to intercept object creation of MEF and return proxy (using castle dynamic proxy) of my object either then the object itself.
is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this.  You could write a custom programming model, or maybe create a TypeCatalog over your own Type object.

Comment: @ktutnik There might be a custom programming model on MefContrib that has support for this: http://github.com/MefContrib/MefContrib  If you do make the hard way I'd suggest you submit it to MefContrib.

Comment: thanks.. i will check the link i hope someone already make one..
actually i found http://kozmic.pl/archive/0001/01/01/meffing-with-castle-windsor.aspx. Windsor has ability for interception, but currently i don't really need IOC that much, MEF injection is enough, it would be nice if MEF has that ability..

Comment: @ktutnik Your link is wrong, I think you meant http://kozmic.net/2009/04/05/meffing-with-castle-windsor/